# Use named parameters with block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I used to have this method:

```
def send_action(action, &success_block)

end
```

Which I could call like this:

```
send_action('PAIR') do
  pp 'test
end
```

Now I want to add an optional parameter:

```
def send_action(action, uuid = nil, &success_block)

end
```

But that doesn't seem to work (which I though).  So I tried writing it with named parameters:

```
def send_action(action:, uuid: nil, &success_block)

end
```

But how can I combine named parameters with a block?

Comment: `def send_action(action, uuid = nil, &success_block)` Works For Me™. What error are you seeing? And what version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both work with Ruby 2.4.4 and 2.6.4. Here's a demonstration with positional parameters.

```
def send_action(action, uuid = nil, &success_block)
  p "#{action} #{uuid}"
  success_block.call
end

send_action("foo") { p 99 }
"foo "
99

send_action("foo", "bar") { p 99 }
"foo bar"
99
```

And with named parameters.

```
def send_action(action:, uuid: nil, &success_block)
  p "#{action} #{uuid}"
  success_block.call
end

send_action(action: "foo") { p 99 }
"foo "
99

send_action(action: "foo", uuid: "bar") { p 99 }
"foo bar"
99
```

Comment: You are correct, I had a missing comma.  Both work fine, thanks for the example!